# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't find IDadditions after trying to run multi-page editor from extension wizard

Tags: plugins, eclipse-rcp, rcp

My goal is get mulipage editor in my RCP application to display SCXML file .

Steps what I did

Plugin.xml> Add > Extention Wizard> Multipage Editor
 Then File Extention as SCXML
 Clicke on Finish

Now plugin.xml looks like this

```
 <editor
            class="generic.layer.editor.v2.editors.MultiPageEditor"
            contributorClass="generic.layer.editor.v2.editors.MultiPageEditorContributor"
            default="true"
            extensions="scxml"
            icon="icons/sample.png"
            id="generic.layer.editor.v2.editors.MultiPageEditor"
            name="Sample Multi-page Editor">
      </editor>
```

Below is code I used to call this new editor

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
                                    IStorage storage = new StringStorage((String)o);
                                       IStorageEditorInput input = new StringInput(storage);
                                       try {
                                        page.openEditor(input, "generic.layer.editor.v2.editors.MultiPageEditor");
                                    } catch (PartInitException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```

related classes for above code

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IStorage;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath;

public class StringStorage implements IStorage{

    private String string;

      StringStorage(String input) {
        this.string = input;
      }

      public InputStream getContents() throws CoreException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes());
      }

      public IPath getFullPath() {
        return null;
      }

      public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
        return null;
      }

      public String getName() {

        return string;
      }

      public boolean isReadOnly() {
        return true;
      }
}
```

Another class needed for above code

```
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IStorage;
import org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.ui.IPersistableElement;
import org.eclipse.ui.IStorageEditorInput;

public class StringInput implements IStorageEditorInput {
    private IStorage storage;
    StringInput(IStorage storage) {this.storage = storage;}
    public boolean exists() {return true;}
    public ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor() {return null;}
    public String getName() {
       return storage.getName();
    }
    public IPersistableElement getPersistable() {return null;}
    public IStorage getStorage() {
       return storage;
    }
    public String getToolTipText() {
       return "String-based file: " + storage.getName();
    }
    public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
      return null;
    }
 }
```

Now I am getting below error

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2019-09-26 13:57:23.246
!MESSAGE Unable to initialize part
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't find IDadditions
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ContributionManager.insertAfter(ContributionManager.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.SubContributionManager.insertAfter(SubContributionManager.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorMenuManager.prependToGroup(EditorMenuManager.java:118)
    at generic.layer.editor.v2.editors.MultiPageEditorContributor.contributeToMenu(MultiPageEditorContributor.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorActionBarContributor.init(EditorActionBarContributor.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorActionBarContributor.init(EditorActionBarContributor.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createEditorActionBars(EditorReference.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:333)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:990)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:955)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:992)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.lambda$0(LazyStackRenderer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4889)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1188)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3098)
    at generic.layer.editor.v2.SCXMLView$1$1.run(SCXMLView.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3820)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at generic.layer.editor.v2.Application.start(Application.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-09-26 13:57:23.247
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.deactivateSite(MultiPageEditorPart.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.dispose(MultiPageEditorPart.java:499)
    at generic.layer.editor.v2.editors.MultiPageEditor.dispose(MultiPageEditor.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.handlePartInitException(CompatibilityPart.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:340)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:990)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:955)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:992)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.lambda$0(LazyStackRenderer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4889)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1188)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3098)
    at generic.layer.editor.v2.SCXMLView$1$1.run(SCXMLView.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3820)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at generic.layer.editor.v2.Application.start(Application.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2019-09-26 13:57:23.249
!MESSAGE Unable to create part
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2019-09-26 13:57:23.249
!MESSAGE can't find IDadditions
```

MultiPageEditorContributor class

```
import org.eclipse.jface.action.*;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.ui.IActionBars;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchActionConstants;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.ui.actions.ActionFactory;
import org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE;
import org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDEActionFactory;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorActionBarContributor;
import org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ITextEditor;
import org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ITextEditorActionConstants;

/**
 * Manages the installation/deinstallation of global actions for multi-page editors.
 * Responsible for the redirection of global actions to the active editor.
 * Multi-page contributor replaces the contributors for the individual editors in the multi-page editor.
 */
public class MultiPageEditorContributor extends MultiPageEditorActionBarContributor {
    private IEditorPart activeEditorPart;
    private Action sampleAction;
    /**
     * Creates a multi-page contributor.
     */
    public MultiPageEditorContributor() {
        super();
        createActions();
    }
    /**
     * Returns the action registed with the given text editor.
     * @return IAction or null if editor is null.
     */
    protected IAction getAction(ITextEditor editor, String actionID) {
        return (editor == null ? null : editor.getAction(actionID));
    }
    /* (non-JavaDoc)
     * Method declared in AbstractMultiPageEditorActionBarContributor.
     */

    public void setActivePage(IEditorPart part) {
        if (activeEditorPart == part)
            return;

        activeEditorPart = part;

        IActionBars actionBars = getActionBars();
        if (actionBars != null) {

            ITextEditor editor = (part instanceof ITextEditor) ? (ITextEditor) part : null;

            actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(
                ActionFactory.DELETE.getId(),
                getAction(editor, ITextEditorActionConstants.DELETE));
            actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(
                ActionFactory.UNDO.getId(),
                getAction(editor, ITextEditorActionConstants.UNDO));
            actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(
                ActionFactory.REDO.getId(),
                getAction(editor, ITextEditorActionConstants.REDO));
            actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(
                ActionFactory.CUT.getId(),
                getAction(editor, ITextEditorActionConstants.CUT));
            actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(
                ActionFactory.COPY.getId(),
                getAction(editor, ITextEditorActionConstants.COPY));
            actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(
                ActionFactory.PASTE.getId(),
                getAction(editor, ITextEditorActionConstants.PASTE));
            actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(
                ActionFactory.SELECT_ALL.getId(),
                getAction(editor, ITextEditorActionConstants.SELECT_ALL));
            actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(
                ActionFactory.FIND.getId(),
                getAction(editor, ITextEditorActionConstants.FIND));
            actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(
                IDEActionFactory.BOOKMARK.getId(),
                getAction(editor, IDEActionFactory.BOOKMARK.getId()));
            actionBars.updateActionBars();
        }
    }
    private void createActions() {
        sampleAction = new Action() {
            public void run() {
                MessageDialog.openInformation(null, "V2", "Sample Action Executed");
            }
        };
        sampleAction.setText("Sample Action");
        sampleAction.setToolTipText("Sample Action tool tip");
        sampleAction.setImageDescriptor(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().
                getImageDescriptor(IDE.SharedImages.IMG_OBJS_TASK_TSK));
    }
    public void contributeToMenu(IMenuManager manager) {
        IMenuManager menu = new MenuManager("Editor &Menu");
        manager.prependToGroup(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS, menu);
        menu.add(sampleAction);
    }
    public void contributeToToolBar(IToolBarManager manager) {
        manager.add(new Separator());
        manager.add(sampleAction);
    }
}
```

Comment: Something wrong in `generic.layer.editor.v2.editors.MultiPageEditorContributor` whatever that is

Comment: @greg-449 Oh it was created automatically(?) after extention wizard. I didn't change anything.  I edited question to include this class

Comment: The `contributeToMenu` method is trying to add to a position in a menu that doesn't exist. If your RCP's menu structure is not the same as the standard Eclipse menus you will have to revise the contributor.